# Are these usr/bin warnings in msys a problem?

Tags: windows, msys2

Following the suggestion of @liberforce, I am running Mingw-w64 64bit shell. 
I got less warnings than with msys2 shell. 
Here are the warnings I got.

```
warning: could not get file information for clang32/
warning: could not get file information for clang32/bin/
warning: could not get file information for clang32/etc/
warning: could not get file information for clang32/etc/config.site
warning: could not get file information for clang32/include/
warning: could not get file information for clang32/lib/
warning: could not get file information for clang32/share/
warning: could not get file information for clang64/
warning: could not get file information for clang64/bin/
warning: could not get file information for clang64/etc/
warning: could not get file information for clang64/etc/config.site
warning: could not get file information for clang64/include/
warning: could not get file information for clang64/lib/
warning: could not get file information for clang64/share/
warning: could not get file information for opt/
warning given when extracting /usr/bin/cygpath.exe (Can't create '/usr/bin/cygpath.exe') 
warning given when extracting /usr/bin/cygwin-console-helper.exe (Can't create '/usr/bin/cygwin-console-helper.exe') 
warning given when extracting /usr/bin/locale.exe (Can't create '/usr/bin/locale.exe') 
warning given when extracting /usr/bin/tzset.exe (Can't create '/usr/bin/tzset.exe') 
warning: terminate MSYS2 without returning to shell and check for updates again
warning: for example close your terminal window instead of calling exit
```

Normally when I  follow the last instruction, when I run the shell again, it just opens the terminal window, quickly shows an error, I can't read quick enough, and quickly closes.
So, I reinstall, and don't use pacman -Syu, to update, but install each module with pacman -S.

However, at this point, I want to know, will the above warnings prove problematic going forward?